# need help making a dynamic query for oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic

So I need to select records from tables that can only be identified at runtime. This is what I've gotten to, but I'm a bit stuck. Any help, suggestions or pointing on how to do this easier/correctly would be greatly appreciated.

```
DECLARE
 TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
 QUERY_STR VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
 SELECT CASE WHEN UPPER(APP.MODULE_LONG_NAME) LIKE 'PLEDGE%' THEN 'PLEDGE_HDR' ELSE 'CONTACT_HDR' END 
 INTO TABLE_NAME
 FROM REQST_HDR RH 
 INNER JOIN LKUP_REQST_TYPE LRT ON LRT.REQST_TYPE_ID = RH.REQST_TYPE_ID
 INNER JOIN APP_MODULE_MSTR APP ON APP.MODULE_ID = LRT.MODULE_ID;

 QUERY_STR := 'SELECT * FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || '--MORE FILTERING';

 --SOMEHOW SHOW RESULTS OF QUERY_STR IN TABLE FORM.
END;
```

Update -
As I couldn't get any of the solutions to work, I ended up just using COALESCE seeing as I only had two tables to base my query off from anyway. Thanks for everyone who answered.

Comment: You need this as a procedure format?

Comment: You'll need a stored proc for this, I reckon.

Comment: not necessarily.. something i can inject pretty easily to c# would be more appreciated.. if a stored proc is the only way i can get it to work then a stored proc it is then.

Comment: Try the `dbms_sql.execute_and_fetch` function. Documentation available on http://www.toadworld.com/KNOWLEDGE/KnowledgeXpertforOracle/tabid/648/TopicID/PLS5K10/Default.aspx

Comment: Also avaliable on Oracle docs at here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/appdev.901/a89852/dbms_sq9.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION choose_a_function_name RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
 TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(255);
 QUERY_STR VARCHAR2(1000);
 res sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
 SELECT CASE WHEN UPPER(APP.MODULE_LONG_NAME) LIKE 'PLEDGE%' THEN 'PLEDGE_HDR' ELSE 'CONTACT_HDR' END 
 INTO TABLE_NAME
 FROM REQST_HDR RH 
 INNER JOIN LKUP_REQST_TYPE LRT ON LRT.REQST_TYPE_ID = RH.REQST_TYPE_ID
 INNER JOIN APP_MODULE_MSTR APP ON APP.MODULE_ID = LRT.MODULE_ID;

 QUERY_STR := 'SELECT * FROM ' || TABLE_NAME || '--MORE FILTERING';

 OPEN res FOR QUERY_STR;

 RETURN res;

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste to see results of below query in table form:

```
DECLARE
  emp_cur_rc      SYS_REFCURSOR;
  emp_rec         scott.emp%ROWTYPE;
  --
  v_sql           VARCHAR2(200);
  v_tab_name      VARCHAR2(200):= 'scott.emp';
  v_field_name    VARCHAR2(200):= 'job';
  v_list          VARCHAR2(200):= '''MANAGER'', ''CLERK''';
BEGIN
  v_sql:= 'SELECT * FROM '|| v_tab_name ||' WHERE '||v_field_name ||' IN ('||v_list||')';

 OPEN emp_cur_rc FOR v_sql;
 LOOP
   FETCH emp_cur_rc INTO emp_rec;
   EXIT WHEN emp_cur_rc%NOTFOUND;
     dbms_output.put_line(emp_rec.empno||chr(9)||emp_rec.ename||chr(9)||emp_rec.job);
 END LOOP;
 CLOSE emp_cur_rc;
END;
/
```